# Define (not declare) c functions inside extern "C" scope

Tags: c++, name-mangling

I saw a section of codes defined **inside** a `.cpp` file like this:

```
extern "C"
{

#include <user_interface.h>
#include <lwip/netif.h>

    uint8 wifi_get_opmode(void)
    {
        return STATION_MODE;
    }   

    bool wifi_station_get_config(struct station_config *config)
    {   
        strcpy((char*)config->ssid, "emulated-ssid");
        strcpy((char*)config->password, "emulated-ssid-password");
        config->bssid_set = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            config->bssid[i] = i;
        return true;
    }
}
```

My understanding of `extern "C"` keyword is to disable name mangling, so the functions **defined inside a `.c` file and compiled with a c compiler** can be linked and called from a cpp code. Which means, these C functions should be defined inside a `.c` file, then they will be compiled to a C-type object file by using a C compiler.

However, here the functions enclosed by `extern "C"` are **defined (not declared) inside a `.cpp` file**. What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Okay, you know how its used to call C from C++. But how do you think C++ code is made available to be called from C?

Comment: @AdrianMole this is needed when authors of packages written in C do not put `extern "C"` in the headers.

Comment: It doesn't generally disable name mangling; it says to use the C compiler's mangling system, which usually means prepending an underscore to the name.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose would be to define the functions using "C" linkage. Meaning: don't mangle their names but compile them just like normal C++ functions would be, otherwise.

They can be called directly from C code that gets linked with this translation unit (subject to a suitable declaration), or from another C++ translation unit that declares these symbols as `extern "C"`.

Comment: Thanks Sam, so the purpose is just to disable name-mangling for this piece of codes. Doing this has the same effect of put these codes into a separate `.c` file.

Comment: No, not quite the same thing. This gets still compiled as C++, instead of C. But this allows C++ code to be called from C code (using `struct`s, object, and types that C understands).

Comment: Remember, C and C++ are different languages, thus in general you cannot just put them into a `.c` file and compile them by a C compiler. The code is still C++, but you can call these functions from C. Essentially, `extern "C"` allows two-way communication between C and C++.

Comment: If you want to call a C function from C++, you will want to **declare** it using `extern "C"` in your C++ file. But if you want to call a C++ function from C (assuming that makes sense) you will want to **define** it in your C++ file using `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually doing this all the time. When you put `extern "C"` in header files, the headers are also included in the implementation file for the functions they declare.

To correctly link a function, the function name must be identical in both the translation unit that defines them and the translation unit that includes them, so you have to use `extern "C"` in both (in the case they are both C++ of course).